# mysql select is not working for IN

Tags: mysql

```
BEGIN
DECLARE cnt1 int(11);
DECLARE cnt2 int(11);
DECLARE demandid varchar(255);
set demandid = replace(pintypeid,';',',');

SELECT 
    COUNT(*) into cnt1
FROM
    UK_Generic_Demand_Details
where status =300 and 
policyNumber =pinpno and
demandTypeId in(Select @demandid) ;

  SELECT
     COUNT(*) into cnt2
 FROM
     UK_Generic_Completed_Demand_Details
     where
      status =300 and 
policyNo =pinpno and
demandTypeId in(select @demandid);
        select cnt1+cnt2 into poutcount; 

END
```

Can some please suggest me in solving this issue.
stored proc will be called from application with pintypeid and policynumber as inputs.
policynumber will be single but pintypeid will be like a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [`find_in_set`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

```
BEGIN
DECLARE cnt1 int(11);
DECLARE cnt2 int(11);
DECLARE demandid varchar(255);
set demandid = replace(pintypeid,';',',');

SELECT 
    COUNT(*) into cnt1
FROM
    UK_Generic_Demand_Details
where status =300 and 
policyNumber =pinpno and
find_in_set(demandTypeId, @demandid) > 0;

  SELECT
     COUNT(*) into cnt2
 FROM
     UK_Generic_Completed_Demand_Details
     where
      status =300 and 
policyNo =pinpno and
find_in_set(demandTypeId, @demandid) > 0;
        select cnt1+cnt2 into poutcount; 

END
```

Comment: @sravan then please add more details to the question - like what will the variable have in it. And what will the column have.